# Optimize live elements' selectors in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, jquery-selectors

I read a lot about optimization in jQuery in some links below:

1. **[jQuery Website , Performance](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/)**
2. **[jQuery Best Practices - Greg Franko](http://gregfranko.com/jquery-best-practices/)**
3. **[jQuery Coding Standards and Best Practices](http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/jquery-standards/)**
4. **[14 Helpful jQuery Tricks, Notes, and Best Practices](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/14-helpful-jquery-tricks-notes-and-best-practices--net-14405)**

and more ... 
But none of them mentioned for .on() caching selectors. I don't know if there is any way to use cached elements in these kind of selectors.

for example I have a lot of these selectors in my `script.js` file.

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu li.remove', function(e){ ... });
$(document).on('click', '.menu li.edit', function(e){ ... });
$(document).on('click', '.menu li.action', function(e){ ... });
$(document).on('click', '.menu li.anotherAction', function(e){ ... });
```

and much more. `.menu` is a menu and can be anywhere in document, so I can't use specific `id` container to select it. like this:

```
$('#sidebar').on('click', '.menu li.action', function(e){ ... });
```

is there any way to optimize these selectors. Checking for existence maybe, caching `.menu` if it is possible.

Comment: Are you facing an actual, practical problem with what you have? jQuery should handle those quite efficiently, and this is a *click* we're talking about, not mousemove or similar... Not like you get several hundred of these a second (and it's not clear that it would be a problem if you were).

Comment: I have lots of these selectors and now my selectors are slower noticably, specially when I click on document to reset things, removing menus, hiding elements, and etc...

Comment: @ Pars: The above will have exactly zero impact on the performance of adding or removing elements in the DOM. jQuery will add one handler for handling `click` on `document`. Only when that handler is actually triggered (e.g., by a click) will it worry about figuring out what callbacks to fire.

Comment: so, is there any way to optimize these selectors ? anyway ?

Comment: @ Pars: You're asking the wrong question. It's extremely unlike that those *need* any further optimization. If you're seeing performance issues adding/removing elements in the DOM, the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Pars: Is there ever a case where an `li.remove` (or the others) is *not* inside a `.menu`? If not, then remove the `.menu` from the selector so that the engine doesn't need to traverse up to find it.

Comment: You cannot really cache the filtering selectors, but you can cache things such as `$(document)` rather than repeatedly create new jQuery objects. However, if your DOM manipulations are slow, it's not because you have many listeners: it's probably because you are generating too many DOM reflows because of the way you chose to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: @six fingered man, lots of the times, there are absent elements in menu. and not just menu, other selectors for other elements, I don't know how to optimize these live selectors for absent elements.

Comment: Optimizations will depend on questions such as that. One other tiny optimization would be to bind to `document.body` instead of `document` so that each selector will be invoked fewer times per click. Also, if the targeted items can never be nested inside each other, you can call `e.stopPropagation()` to stop the manual bubbling once an element is found.

Comment: @sixfingeredman: *"One other tiny optimization would be to bind to document.body instead of document so that each selector will be invoked fewer times per click."* What makes you think using `$(document).click(...)` will be "invoked" more than once?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: The handler won't, and the binding certainly won't. I'm talking about the selector being compared multiple times. It  starts with the `e.target` and as it manually bubbles up each ancestor, it runs a match of the selector against the current element. Binding to the `body` makes that manual bubbling stop a tiny bit sooner.

Comment: @sixfingeredman: Ah, I see what you mean.

Comment: @Pars: If you really need optimization, just do your own manual delegation. That way it can be tailored to your specific need instead of relying on a selector engine inside a broad abstraction. That should improve performance.

Comment: @sixfingeredman Even if the event bubbles 100 times or doesn't bubble at all, the target is only filtered once. The filtering occurs when the event reaches the element on which the event was attached. Perhaps I misunderstood what you said?

Comment: @plalx: I think the point is once it's hit `document`, jQuery has to start with `e.target` and compare with the selector; then go to the parent; then *its* parent, etc. So if it's (say) `div > span > body > document` that's (perhaps) four checks, but if it's `div > span > body` that's probably three checks. That said, I'd have to look at the jQuery source, it would be really dumb to compare a selector against `document`. And in any case, the difference really would be miniscule (on a click; again, perhaps mousemove, but click?).

Comment: @plalx: Like TJ said. Since the selector could match any element between the `e.target` and the bound element, it needs to start at the `e.target` and manually bubble up, performing a selector match every time. So if you have 20 handlers bound this way, and you click on an element nested 10 elements deep, that means the selector match is going to be performed 200 times for that one click.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yes, the difference would be minuscule. In either case, jQuery doesn't call the selector against the bound element, so it would halt once `node === this`. For example `$(document.body).on("click", "body", function() {})` won't invoke the handler. However, I'm pretty sure it's actually a difference of two levels, since it has to go past the `document.documentElement` as well.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh ok yeah, I get what you mean. I thought the selector was checked against the target only when it reached the element on which the listener was attached to, but it can't be or event delegation would not work properly with deeply nested elements that aren't leafs.

Comment: I thought it's better to use only class selectors instead of tag.class in left hand side of selectors, but in this link, #2 says use tag.class, is this true ? http://www.sitepoint.com/efficient-jquery-selectors/

Comment: @Pars: Probably depends on the selector engine. Only testing will tell. If you do a DOM selection for a certain class, and you know that it will always have the same tag name (or if you don't care about the tag name), then it's less work to only compare each node's class than to compare both class and tagName. So in your case, sure if you don't care whether or not the class is on a `li` element, then remove the `li` part. Only you can decide that. But testing will tell you if it actually makes a difference.

Comment: thank you Mr six fingered man, you really helped me, especially with your manual delegation... And this is the test for class selectior and tag.class selector. http://jsperf.com/jquery-class-vs-tag-qualfied-class-selector/2. in this test, class selectors do better.

Comment: @Pars: Although to be thorough, you may want to do a performance test that uses `$(elem).is("my_selector")` and test it against elements where both tag and class match, where only one or the other matches and were neither match. Let's say the class matches, but the tag doesn't. If they test the tag first, and it fails, it would avoid the class test, which is more expensive. So it may be worth some examination.

Comment: @sixfingeredman: re "One other tiny optimization would be to bind to document.body instead of document so that each selector will be invoked fewer times per click." `body` is an unreliable target for delegated events. Styling can give it a calculated height of zero and it will then *stop responding to delegated click events*! Always use `document` as the default if nothing closer exists. :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: That's a good point, but I would hope that a developer would know about the styling being used. Doesn't seem like too high an expectation. :)

Comment: @six fingered man: A zero body height is not always apparent as it results from absolute positioning of child elements, something that some plugins can do without your knowledge. better to err on the side of caution as it is one trivial lookup difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to eek out every last bit of performance, you probably need to ditch abstractions.

If you do your own delegation, you'll certainly see a performance improvement.

Because in the example you gave, all the delegation is identical except for the class name, I'd bind a single handler, put the code in separate functions, and then examine the `e.target` and its ancestors manually looking for the `.menu li`. If that's found, then check the class of the `li`, and invoke the correct handler.

```
var handlers = {
    remove: function() {/*your code*/},
    edit: function() {/*your code*/},
    action: function() {/*your code*/},
    anotherAction: function() {/*your code*/}
};

var targets = Object.keys(handlers);

document.onclick = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var li;
    var node = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var targetClass;

    do {
        if (!li) {
            if (node.nodeName === "LI") {
                li = node;
            }
        } else if (node.className.indexOf("menu") > -1) {
            targetClass = li.className
            break;
        }
    } while(node = node.parentNode);

    if (!targetClass)
        return;

    for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
        if (targetClass.indexOf(targets[i]) > -1) {
            handlers[targets[i]].call(li, e);
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, as we traverse up from the `e.target`, we first check to see if we're on an `li`. If so, grab it and continue one.

As we continue, we no longer need to check for `li` elements, but we now need to check for an element with the `menu` class. If we find one, we grab the class name of the `li` we previously found and then halt the loop.

We now know we have our `menu li.someClass` element. So then we can use the class that we found on the `li` to look up the proper function to invoke from our list of functions we made above.

---

You should note that my `.indexOf()` class testing is ad hoc, and could result in false positives. You should improve it. Also, the code needs more tweaking since we're caching the `li` without knowing if it actually has a class that we're interested in. That should be fixed as well.

I'll leave it to you to add the necessary tweaks if you desire. :-)

Comment: Unless you are getting many 1000s of mouse operations per second (which is never the case), you have traded readability/maintainability/code-size for a small speed increase *that will never be noticed*. You have also mentioned that the code above may also have introduced new bugs! For all these *pragmatic* reasons this is actually a bad answer. Sorry.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: The bugs are simply that I didn't do a full implementation. There's nothing wrong with actually writing a little code every once in a while. In any case, he's asking about optimization, and targeted event delegation will be much faster than jQuery's generalized delegation. It's up to him if it's worth doing. The point is to help him understand how such concepts work.

Comment: If that actually helped him "understand how such concepts work", then I hope he accepts your answer, but "fast/slow" are subjective terms here. I think your code could use a few comments to aid readability as it is a real `TL;DR` example that does the same as a previously trivial code-snippet :)

Comment: If speed is really an issue, I have posted an answer that will improve the delegation speed, trading it for multiple delegated event handlers. This should be more than *fast enough* ("enough" also being a subjective term) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: The premise of the question is full document level delegation. Naturally localized delegation would be preferable.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: I'll let the OP let you know if that's what he intended. Maybe I'm reading it wrong, but I think that's what's meant by *"...`.menu` is a menu and can be anywhere in document, so I can't use specific id container to select it."* Seems like the menu appears at different points, but maybe I'm reading too much into it.

Comment: I read it the same, but the lack of an "id container" does not stop you targetting *all* the `.menu` elements with delegated handlers. :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: I meant that I assumed the `.menu` elements themselves were dynamically appearing anywhere in the document, in which case they wouldn't be available to select and bind with a `".menu"` selector. I may be wrong though.

Comment: Ah, no. I did not get that impression. Their `#sidebar` example made me think they were just all anonymous (*id-wise*). We will have to await the SO's return... one day... perhaps... :)

Answer (score 0):

I personally think you are worrying about speed where speed is not an issue.

If the menus are not loaded dynamically, there is nothing stopping you from combining delegated event handlers with normal jQuery selectors to target more of the *closer* elements (e.g. your `.menu` class):

e.g.

```
$('.menu').on('click', 'li.remove', function(e){ ... })
 .on('click', 'li.edit', function(e){ ... })
 .on('click', 'li.action', function(e){ ... })
 .on('click', 'li.anotherAction', function(e){ ... });
```

This will create a handler on each menu (so closer to the elements).

If your menus are dynamically loaded, then your existing code is *perfectly fine*, as my understanding is that *delegated event handlers* only apply the `selector` argument to the elements in the bubble chain. If that is the case, delegated events will be pretty darn fast anyway. *Certainly faster than you can click your mouse!* I have never had speed issue with delegated event handlers and I probably overuse them in my plugins (I always assume dynamic content in those).